# method Md5PasswordEncoder() doesn't work for me in spring5

Tags: spring, md5

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    private DataSource datasource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(datasource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery("select username as principal, password as credentials, active"
                + " from users where username = ? ").authoritiesByUsernameQuery
        ("select username as principal, role as role from users_roles where username = ?")
        .rolePrefix("ROLE_")
        .Md5PasswordEncoder());
    }
```

//// i have already crypted my password in DataBase with MD5 , but when trying to calling  this method (to decrypt my password )it doesn't work or it even doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are wrong here. The MD5 is one-way algorithm. There is no way to decrypt it [Check this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.M5/api/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/Md5PasswordEncoder.html) (except brute-force with lot of computation power). So you have encrypt your password using MD5 and it will be checked against the password in db. So for that purpose you have to set AuthenticationProvider (with passwordEncoder. (here md5 passwordEncoder)) on your AuthenticationManagerBuilder instance.

Note: MD5 / SHA 1 are vulnerable so try BCryptPasswordEncoder ([Brute-force: Bcrypt vs MD5](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61385/the-brute-force-resistence-of-bcrypt-versus-md5-for-password-hashing))

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
@Autowired
private DataSource datasource;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
{
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());  
}

 @Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authenticationProvider;
 }

 @Bean
 public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new Md5PasswordEncoder();
 }
}

@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String ssoId)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
   // Your custom query to get the userDetails should go here.
 }
}
```

Comment: please explain for me this lines because they don't work for me (they are chekcked with red color)
private UserService userService;
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService

Comment: I have now removed the UserService. The UserService is your custom service to get the user details from db.I havent provided the implementation since I dont know the dao layer details that you are using. you can directly autowire your dao layer class/interface (in case of jpa) to fetch the user details details.

Comment: btw what dao implementation you are using spring jdbc or Spring data JPA?